# Get employee and his manager details without joins

Tags: sql, performance

I have a table **Employee** which contains **Employee id** and **Manager id**. 
I want to get **Employee id**, Employee's **Manager id**, and Employee's manager's **Manager id**.

I can get it using self join and other joins like

```
Select employe id, Manager id 
from emplyee as a, employee as b 
where a.manager_id  = b.employee id
```

But is there a better way? Can we do this without joins, by only querying the table once?

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.

Comment: You can use subquery. However, join is better.

Comment: There is a better way: use a proper explicit `JOIN` operator instead of the outdated, ancient implicit join in the where clause.

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (Performance questions are almost always product specific.)

Comment: What do you mean by proper  explicit JOIN ? Will you be able to elaborate it more with example?

Comment: Explicit join: `select ... from t1 join t2 on t1.c1 = t2.c2`. Implicit join: `select .. from t1, t2 where t1.c1 = t2.c2`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  recursive CTE  but still you have to use a join

Look at this example:

```
WITH MyCTE
AS (
    SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID
    FROM Employee
    WHERE ManagerID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT EmpID, FirstName, LastName, ManagerID
    FROM Employee
      INNER JOIN MyCTE ON Employee.ManagerID = MyCTE.EmpID
    WHERE Employee.ManagerID IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT *
FROM MyCTE
```

please refer to this link for detail of CTE by Pinal Dave

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/04/24/sql-server-introduction-to-hierarchical-query-using-a-recursive-cte-a-primer/

Comment: Please provide indentation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't consider a co-related subquery as a join you can do this:

```
Select e.employee_id, 
       e.manager_id, 
       (select manager_id  
        from employee e2
        where e2.employee_id = e.manager_id) as employee_manager_id
from employee e;
```

But at some point you *have* to do some kind of "join".